# performance of nspropertylistserialization vs nsjsonserialization

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, json, cocoa, plist

I'm considering making a switch from serializing data from my web service endpoint as JSON to a binary property list. I'm unserializing on Cocoa. Has anyone who has used both `NSPropertyListSerialization` and `NSJSONSerialization` noticed a difference in parsing times?  I'm curious as I've read before that there's a noticeable difference—see [this blog post](http://blog.hipmunk.com/post/6493884712/hipmunk-for-iphone-post-mortem) (in the Under the Hood section) for an example by Hipmunk.

Also interesting to me if there's a noticeable difference between NSJSONSerialization and external libraries like [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).

Comment: Good question but note that I'm not sure you will have an answer here, as iOS5 is still under NDA

Comment: Are you interested in both iOS and Mac OS X or is it iOS only?

Comment: Either, as I don't think this sort of thing is specific to one or the other. I'm working on iOS, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that `NSJSONSerialization` is faster than JSONKit, I used it for a Core Graphics project and code which took on average 26ms before is now 16ms, with only changes in the JSON deserialization.

Not sure on `NSPropertyListSerialization`, but the [GitHub](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) page of JSONKit claims it's faster than binary .plist, which leads me to believe that `NSJSONSerialization` class is the fastest of them all. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just realized that the original post is almost 2 months old, hope no-one minds, I stumbled upon this while looking for the same answer and after doing tests wanted to share.

Answer (score 2):

I pulled down 200 tweets and profiled parsing the payload using both SBJSON and NSJSONSerialization.  The results:

SBJSON: 489ms / 397KB
NSJSONSerialization : 133ms / 3.8 KB

NSJSONSerialization has a pretty significant advantage - especially in terms of the memory footprint.

http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance

Comment: link no longer work, but you can look in archive http://web.archive.org/web/20130526040540/http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance